# Relative velocity during a collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, collision, relative-motion

I quote Resonance Kota module on Mechanics(Vol.1):

> The collision is just avoided if relative velocity becomes zero just at the moment the two cars meet each other.

I don't understand why should it be so?

Comment: if there is no relative velocity, both bodies or cars will move with same velocity. that is they would be at rest with respect to each other

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is an underlying assumption that both the cars are moving in the same direction.

Now, if there is no relative velocity between the cars, then obviously they won't collide. Having zero relative velocity just means that the cars are moving at the same speeds.

If you are in a car moving at 100 miles per hour and the car in front of you is also moving at the same speed, then you won't collide with that car even though both of you are travelling at high speeds!